# Using "For-Next" inside "If" (Excel, VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to combine multiple **"If"s** and one **"For-Next"** statement inside a single **"If"** (code follows). Unfortunately I am always get an error message: *"Compile Error: Else without If"*. Can you look at my code for mistakes?

```
Sub Debugging()

Workbooks("Problem.xls").Worksheets(1).Activate

Cash_Rows = 5
Share_Rows = 6

If Cash_Rows <= Share_Rows Then

    Range("A1:A" & Cash_Rows).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419

    Count_Cash = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "L*")

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cash_Rows)
        If CStr(cell.Value) Like "L*" Then
        Range("A" & cell.Row & ":" & "D" & cell.Row).Interior.Color = 65535
        Dim Index As Integer
        Index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(cell.Value), Range("F2:" & "F" & Share_Rows), 0)
        Range("F" & Index & ":" & "I" & Index).Interior.Color = 65535
        End If
    Next

    If Count_Cash = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You do not have any matching ID+Amount between Cash and Shares booking. It's OK!"
    Else
        MsgBox "You have " & Count_Cash & " matching transactions. Check them!"
    End If

Else

MsgBox "Do not worry. Be happy!"

End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: you're missing `End With` after `.TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to end the `with`.

```
With Selection.Interior
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
End With
```

Comment: Just to add a word of explanation to this succinct and correct answer. You can nest an `IF ... END IF` within a `WITH ... END WITH` (and the opposite way around) but overlapping sets of statements are not allowed. So VBA is trying to match your last `ELSE` to an `IF` coming after your `WITH` - and it can't, hence the error message. Like most compilers/interpreters VBA is dumb but logical - reading the error messages and working out what's really gone wrong will come with experience.

Comment: Thank you all very much!
It was very helpful!

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking the tick next to an answer if it was of use to help other users with the same issue.